# Kobold Tunnelers - Does shifting as an immediate interrupt prevent damage by nullifying a hit?

Tags: dnd-4e

Encounter number 2 *Worship* in *The Twisting Halls* adventure - part of the Red Box set contains **Kobold Tunnelers** (minions) with the following ability:

**Triggered Actions**:
`Narrow Escape` At-Will Immediate Interrupt
*Trigger*: A close or an area attack hits or misses the Kobold
*Effect*: The Kobold rolls a saving throw. If it succeeds it shifts 3 squares.

Three cases came up, and for a new 4e DM, I felt uncertain of the correct rules - given that this is the red-box adventure, it'd be good to teach all new DMs the correct way to think about these things.

1. Magic Missile - as per other questions here, does not "Hit" so any Kobold minion on the other end of that spell is dead. No saving throw. Right?
2. Surprise - The party had a surprise round on two of the Kobolds, so I ruled that the interrupt didn't happen. With combat advantage, two more dead monsters. I'm not sure if this is right. **Does surprise negate triggered effects?** If not, the next sub-question applies:
3. I had no problem dealing with a attack missing, save == shift 3. The thing that had me unsure was when a party member hits (which would auto-kill the minion), and the kobold makes his saving throw in order to shift - does the hit fail (which spares the Kobold) or cancel the damage (which, would kill? a minion?)

Comment: The key word on their power is "interrupt".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Magic Missile<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=463)</sup> is not affected.  It is a `Ranged` attack, not a `Close` or `Area` attack
2. Surprised<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=145)</sup> is a condition.  One of its effects is that no actions can be taken by the surprised creatures.  An `Immediate Interrupt` is a form of `Immediate Action`, so it cannot be taken while surprised.
3. The Immediate Interrupt<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=120)</sup> invalidates the attack against the kobold (assuming the shift gets him out of range.

> An immediate interrupt lets you jump in when a certain trigger condition arises, acting before the trigger resolves. If an interrupt invalidates a triggering action, that action is lost. For example, an enemy makes a melee attack against you, but you use a power that lets you shift away as an immediate interrupt. If your enemy can no longer reach you, the enemy’s attack action is lost.

Comment: Those are the references I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

1. `Narrow Escape` only applies to `Close` and `Area` attacks (i.e. `Close Blast 3` or `Burst 2 within 10`, etc.). So `Magic Missile` isn't affected, since it is a `Ranged` power.
2. Immediate Actions are allowed in a surprise round (*Rules Compendium* p. 191):

   > During a surpise round (but not on its turn), the creature is can take an immediate action, as well as opportunity actions.

   **But**,

   > If a creature is surprised, it can't take any actions, not even free actions, during the surprise round.

   So you're ruling that the kobolds couldn't use the `Narrow Escape` if they were surprised was correct.
3. Since `Narrow Escape` only applies for `Close` and `Area` attacks, their goal is to shift out of the area of effect and not be hit. They interrupt the `Fireball` or other area attack and jump out of the way just in the nick of time. That's why it's called `Narrow Escape`.

Comment: Interesting. My results may have been correct even if my reading was incorrect.